# Using ROS without gazebo_ros_pkgs?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I made a project using Gazebo and plugins to simulate a Robot. ROS is now not even installed on my computer. I wonder if I can use the roscpp librairy to integrate ROS in my project, without using the gazebo_ros_pkgs. The reason why I want to do like this is that I would like to compare my own IK algorithm to common ones available with ROS, and therefore integrate ROS in my Gazebo model_plugin.

As you might guess, I don't really know the ROS environnement. Just tell me if my question doesn't make sens!

Best.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12048/using-ros-without-gazebo_ros_pkgs-?/) by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 198 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You don't need to use `gazebo_ ros_pkgs` in order to use ROS with Gazebo. In fact, `gazebo_ros_pkgs` consists mostly of Gazebo plugins that have some component of ROS.

I'd recommend looking at the source code of `gazebo_ros_pkgs` for tips and ideas on integrating ROS with your own Gazebo plugins. Here is a good [example](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_laser.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1